# Discord.js "cannot read properties of undefined" when trying to put event handler into a seperate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, event-handling

So I have been working on a discord bot. At first, I've put every event handler into index.js, which worked perfectly well.

```
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], 
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        await interaction.reply('There was an error while executing this command!');
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "test");
    let message = 874736592542105640;
    let emotes = [ "kannathinking", ""];
    let roleID = (reaction.emoji.name == emotes[0] ? "874730080486686730" : "874729987310235738")

    if (message == reaction.message.id && (emotes[0] == reaction.emoji.name || emotes[1] == reaction.emoji.name)) {
    channel.send(`${user} was given the <@&${roleID}> role`);
    }
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "test");
    let message = 874736592542105640;
    let emotes = [ "kannathinking", ""];
    let roleID = (reaction.emoji.name == emotes[0] ? "874730080486686730" : "874729987310235738")

    if (message == reaction.message.id && (emotes[0] == reaction.emoji.name || emotes[1] == reaction.emoji.name)) {
    channel.send(`${user} was removed from the <@&${roleID}> role`);
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Then I tried storing the event-handlers in seperate files, just like I did with the commands.

```
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS],
partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'], 
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('js'));
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync('./events').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
client.login(token);
```

This however didn't work well. As I started the bot it gave me positive feedback. As soon as I tried to react to a message on my discord server however, it threw the following error:

> TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

The messageReactionAdd.js event file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'messageReactionAdd',
    execute(client, reaction, user) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "test");
        let message = 874736592542105640;
        let emotes = ["kannathinking", ""];
        let roleID = (reaction.emoji.name == emotes[0] ? "874730080486686730" : "874729987310235738")

        if (message == reaction.message.id && (emotes[0] == reaction.emoji.name || emotes[1] == reaction.emoji.name)) {
            channel.send(`${user} was given the <@&${roleID}> role`);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried fixing the error by requiring the client object I created in index.js, aswell as requiring "Client" from discord.js. Both didn't work and I can't figure out what is missing in the event file so that it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When requiring the event file, you never defined client therefore when you call `client.channels` in the event handler, it doesn't actually know what `client` is.

To fix this issue, when executing the function, define client before the args.
Example:

```js
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
    }
}
```